# How to create a secured mysql server only for data processing

Tags: mysql

I want to create a secured server (mysql server) only for data processing.

For example:
 client passes in a xml file from HTTP POST, and the server receive it and parse the xml, then store data into database. or the client make HTTP request, and server calculate the result, and return a xml to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a script on the server like in PHP to handle the processing of the request(s)? That will do the trick quite easily?

A pure MySQL solution might be possible but will be quite hard actually since parsing XML and things are most simply done in some scripting language.

To do this nicely a simple API would be my preferred solution, that way there is a clear seperation on accessing the secured server.

You state "secured" which is bit vague so which authentication protocols might be needed cannot be stated based on the general question posted.

Comment: alright, this gives me a general idea how it can be done. thanks a lot.

Comment: tnx, you might want to put up another question about your security. Can't figure out on the info in this question how important it is but if security is important think it well through.